# What is the relation between HZ and bps?

Tags: networking, bandwidth, frequency

The bandwidth in EE = width of frequency band, measured in Hz, and in CS= information carrying capacity, in bits/sec,
So what is the relation between hz and bps and how to covert between each other?

Comment: You need to know the SNR of the channel. Read up on [Shannon's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noisy-channel_coding_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a place for software not hardware
2. You did not give enough information or context and showed no effort towards a solution
3. The relation depends on the modulation scheme and is called modulation efficiency. A number like 20 (bits per second)/(hz) is reasonable. So, if I say your modem has a bandwidth of 3khz you should expect 3000*20 bits per second, or 60K